# how to use svn copy / svn rename commands in windows bat file

Tags: svn, batch-file, tortoisesvn, dos

We use the following command for `svn update` in windows bat file:

```
"%SVN%\TortoiseProc.exe" /command:update /path:"%SOURCE%" /closeonend:2
```

How can we use `svn copy` and `svn rename` commands?

Comment: By putting these commands in the bat file. What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the [TortoiseSVN documentation](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html), you can use the `/command:copy` of Tortoise but it will bring up the up the branch/tag dialog.

It's the same thing with `/command:rename`, the new name for the file is asked with a dialog.

But you can do the same operations using the SVN command line client:

```
svn copy "https://pathToRepo/trunk" "https://pathToRepo/myBranch"
```

and

```
svn rename "https://pathToRepo/oldName.file" "https://pathToRepo/newName.file"
```

Both commands work with both working copy paths or URLs.

Comment: When installing TortoiseSVN, you can check an option to install also the SVN command line tools. Then, to create a branch or tag from a specific revision of your trunk, you can do: `svn copy -m 'created branch from rev 100' svn://myrepo/trunk@100 svn://myrepo/branches/newbranch`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [the documentation](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html). It lists the commands you can use and its arguments.

You cannot use `copy` and `rename` non-interactively, though. For automating things in a Subversion repository you should use the command-line Subversion client.

Answer (score 1):

To use SVN CLI commands, you *should* use SVN, not TortoiseSVN, which is just a frontend.